# Extending SOShipLineSplit DAC not working properly for Shipments Allocations

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to extend the Allocations SOShipLineSplit DAC without success.

**1st approach: Using Usr fields in the same table.**

- An integer and a boolean field were added using the customization project interface.
- The extended DAC was defined as follows:

  ```
      public class SOShipLineSplitExtended : PXCacheExtension<SOShipLineSplit>
      {
          #region UsrentryA
          public abstract class usrentryA : PX.Data.IBqlField
          {
          }
          [PXDBInt]
          [PXDefault(6, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
          [PXUIField(DisplayName = "UsrEntryA")]
          public virtual int? UsrentryA { get; set; }
          #endregion
          #region UsrentryB
          public abstract class usrentryB : PX.Data.IBqlField
          {
          }
          [PXDBBool]
          [PXDefault(true, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
          [PXUIField(DisplayName = "UsrEntryB")]
          public virtual Boolean? UsrentryB { get; set; }
          #endregion
      }
  ```
- Finally the fields were added in the UI (although this is not needed in our project).

When a Sales Order is created and then its corresponding Shipment is also created, the information is persisted correctly in the DB:

```
Select UsrentryA, UsrEntryB from SOShipLineSplit
where ShipmentNbr = '001713'
```

[Persisted Correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTnmK.png)

However, immediately after confirming the shipment, those fields are being set to NULL

[NULL values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0StlS.png)

**2nd approach: As a workaround, I tried to create an extended table**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SOShipLineSplitStandalone](
    [CompanyID]                         [int] NOT NULL,
    [ShipmentNbr]                       [nvarchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [LineNbr]                           [int] NOT NULL,
    [SplitLineNbr]                      [int] NOT NULL,
    --Extended Fields
    [FieldInteger]              [int] NULL,
    [FieldBool]                 [bit] NULL
    --
CONSTRAINT [SOShipLineSplitStandalone_PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
    (
    [CompanyID] ASC,
    [ShipmentNbr] ASC,
    [LineNbr] ASC,
    [SplitLineNbr] ASC
    )
)
END
```

with this corresponding DAC:

```
namespace SOShipLineSplitNS
{
    [PXTable(typeof(SOShipLineSplit.shipmentNbr), typeof(SOShipLineSplit.lineNbr), typeof(SOShipLineSplit.splitLineNbr), IsOptional = true)]
    public class SOShipLineSplitStandalone : PXCacheExtension<SOShipLineSplit>
    {
        #region FieldInteger
        public abstract class fieldInteger : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBInt]
        [PXDefault(7, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FieldInteger")]
        public virtual int? FieldInteger { get; set; }
        #endregion

        #region FieldBool
        public abstract class fieldBool : PX.Data.IBqlField
        {
        }
        [PXDBBool]
        [PXDefault(true, PersistingCheck = PXPersistingCheck.Nothing)]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "FieldBool")]
        public virtual Boolean? FieldBool { get; set; }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

In this case, when a SO is created and then its Shipment is also created, no records are inserted in the extended table:
[Original and Extended tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NGdT.png)

Any ideas as to how to prevent the Usr fields from this table from being set to null during the Shipment confirmation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because SOShipLineSplit comes from 3 partial class in  different namespaces. 
[image]

The workaround is to declare your custom fields in all 3 namespaces (copy/paste):

```
public class SOShipLineSplitPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOShipLineSplit>
{
    // Your custom fields here
}

namespace Unassigned
{
    public class SOShipLineSplitPXExt : PXCacheExtension<SOShipLineSplit>
    {
       // Your custom fields here
    }
}

namespace Table
{
    public class SOShipLineSplitPXExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.SO.Table.SOShipLineSplit>
    {
       // Your custom fields here
    }
}
```